# Why the insert method of list does not work correctly in my recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, insert

I am trying to reverse a list via recursion

```
def my_rev1(data):
    if len(data) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        head = data[:-1]
        tail = data[-1]
        my_rev1(head).insert(0, tail)  # does not work property
        return head


def my_rev2(data):
    if len(data) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        head = data[:-1]
        tail = data[-1]
        return [tail] + my_rev2(head)  # correct


print("my_rev1")
print(my_rev1([1]))
print(my_rev1([1, 2, 3]))

print("my_rev2")
print(my_rev2([1]))
print(my_rev2([1, 2, 3]))
```

The output is:

```
my_rev1
[]
[1, 2]
my_rev2
[1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

I wonder why the first recursive function is not correct? What is the difference between the 2 function?

Comment: Because `my_rev1(head).insert(0, tail)` returns a *new list* which you then use `.insert` on, but you never maintain a reference to that new list, so it gets discsarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here

```
my_rev1(head).insert(0, tail)
```

is the issue. The result from calling `my_rev1` isn't being stored anywhere.

So you need something like this:

```
rev_head = my_rev1(head)
rev_head.insert(0, tail)
return rev_head
```

Comment: I agree. Thank you kimbo!